# C++11 vector insert causes invalid access

Tags: c++11, vector, dll

I'm writing a DLL for some features and seeing a strange problem.
If I use the below code in my DLL and try to load it, it throws the error:

```
// Sample code
uint8_t data[SIZE_MAX]; // SIZE_MAX = 15
std::vector<uint8_t> v(data, data + SIZE_MAX);
// more code
std::vector<uint8_t> appendData; // initialize it with some value
v.insert(v.end(), appendData.begin(), appendData.end());

ERROR:
LoadLibraryW failed with error (3E6): Invalid access to memory location.
```

I have been using the same code for a while and it always worked. However, it stopped working suddenly and I'm not sure what exactly is causing this error. Any pointers?

Comment: Are you calling this code in your DLL's entry point function?

Comment: No. In fact, it has been working just fine for long time.

Comment: The code you have shown does not call `LoadLibrary()`, and cannot cause a `LoadLibrary()` error if it is not being used in `DllEntryPoint`. Something else is going on. In what context are you seeing the `LoadLibrary()` error?

Comment: Oh I see. The LoadLibraryW() is being called from another module which is loading the DLL with this code. Quite possible something else is going on. I will debug my code a bit more.